# YTD on single bar chart - using Slicer for month selection (PowerBI)

Tags: powerbi, dax, bar-chart, slicers

I would like to create a DAX that will make my visual (a single bar chart) display the YTD of a data [see below]

[image]

On top of that, I want it to be interactive to a slicer - in a way that i will only select a single month (example: August) & it will show data from Jan-Aug automatically.

Comment: Lookup/search `DAX TOTALYTD`

Comment: However, I am using a 'disconnected' calendar table for my slicer.. reason: i am making it interactive with other visual (monthly chart - Jan to selected month).. hence, using TOTALYTD DAX will not be as simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a disconnected date table:

```
MyTotalYTD = 
  TOTALYTD(
    SUM('factTable'[Amount]),
    'connectedDateTable'[Date],
    FILTER(
      ALL('connectedDateTable'[Date]),
      'connectedDateTable'[Date] <= MAX('disconnectedDateTable'[Date])
    )
  )

// or

MyTotalYTD = 
  TOTALYTD(
    SUM('factTable'[Amount]),
    'factTable'[Date],
    FILTER(
      ALL('factTable'[Date]),
      'factTable'[Date] <= MAX('disconnectedDateTable'[Date])
    )
  )
```

Comment: Hi just wondering if you know the reason as to why i cant apply this in a Pie/Donut Chart?

Comment: Not sure - what issue are you having? You should be able to add the measure to the Values well of the chart. Is the measure numeric?

Comment: All good now, I accidentally created one with a 'new column' rather than 'new measure'..